# I am getting error when i click submit button in jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, servlets, eclipse-neon

I have taken reference from ->

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-make-my-first-JSP-page-using-MySQL-database

At first jsp file is opening , i can input data but after clicking at submit , it gives error as in the image provided.

i m using tomcat v7.0 and it works correct for all other projects !

[image: Here is the image what i m gettting error at]

code->

Login.jsp file

```
     <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
      pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
     <html>
      <head>
         <title>Register form</title>
      </head>
      <body>
    <form method="post" action="register">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
    Email ID:<input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
    Password:<input type="text" name="pass" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="register" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Register.java file

```
         import java.io.*;
         import javax.servlet.*;
         import javax.servlet.http.*;
         import java.sql.*;

         public class Register extends HttpServlet {

         protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
          HttpServletResponse response)

         throws ServletException, IOException {
          response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    try{

    //loading drivers for mysql
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //creating connection with the database 
      Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
                 ("jdbc:mysql:/ 
      /localhost:3306/test","username","password");

     PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
              ("insert into Student values(?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1, name);
    ps.setString(2, email);
    ps.setString(3, pass);
    int i=ps.executeUpdate();

      if(i>0)
      {
        out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
      }else{
          out.println("Invalid User");  
        }

    }
    catch(Exception se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add web.xml as in tutorial the servlet

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Register</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: actually i have given in the code , but it is in template format so i cant send the code , if you can answer I will mail you the image of the xml file :)

Comment: but please help , I have to complete my project . :)